# Replace text with hostname script?

Tags: bash, sed

I need to change the same file on multiple servers and replace it with the hostname of the server.

```
sed -i 's/localhost/myhostname/g' /var/www/config.php
```

Is what I currently do.

How would I turn it into a script so that it will automatically check what the servers hostname is and replace "myhostname" with the servers hostname?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch to double quotes and you can add a variable or command substitution.

```
sed -i "s/localhost/$HOSTNAME/g" /var/www/config.php
sed -i "s/localhost/$(hostname)/g" /var/www/config.php
```